# Looking for a way to use jQuery Chosen in a Fabrik dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, fabrik

The Fabrik Dropdown (and all other SELECT) plugins present results as a standard SELECT html format.
What I am looking for is a quick way of replacing this with a jQuery CHOSEN field to improve the usability of dropdowns.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Hugh. Please take our [tour] and read [ask].  Your requirements seem clear enough, have you taken any steps to resolve this yourself?  It give a question clearer context and often makes a question easier for volunteers to answer if you show how far you've gone on your own with researching and coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this functionality is built into Fabrik, but has to be manually enabled, to do so:
Open Fabrik Component Options in Administrator
In the Forms Tab:
Set Enhanced Dropdowns either to per element or to yes (if set to per element, then this also needs to be enabled on a per element basis in the element)

Note this function is marked as WIP (Work in Progress) in Fabrik 3.9.2

Comment: It's a WIP, but for me it has worked well so far.